# Foreign investment with US equity; typical expected rate of return?

Tags: interest-rate, investment

I have been trying to answer this question but cannot find a suitable dataset or compilation.

When a US investor invests in a non-US project what are typical rates of return he is looking for?

I do realize that these rates will (obviously) vary with the risk of individual projects, sector, project size etc. But is there any dataset that may allow some analysis of this factor?

To provide some context, I was looking at a prospectus for a Asian country manufacturing project that has been pitched to American private investors and offers a 10% post-tax return on investment. Just wanted a ballpark evaluation of whether this would be a reasonable return.

The risk is low to moderate and the sector is specialty chemicals manufacturing.